# List of user_friends is empty Facebook SDK 3.14.1

Tags: facebook-graph-api-v2.0

With this code i want to extract a list of my Friends and as next step all of the last checkins of my friends but the list is always empty.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid,name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN "
                    + "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25)";
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + response.toString());

                    try {
                        GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();

                        Log.d("data", jsonObject.toString());
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                        System.out.println("länge array" + array.length());

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) { //

                            JSONObject friend = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            Log.d("uid", friend.getString("uid"));
                            Log.d("name", friend.getString("name"));

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

}
```

also i want to get all checkins of my friends but the data is empty 
I would happy if someone could help me out

Output of LogCat:

```
{ "data": []}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Facebook API v2.0, friends list (/me/friends and FQL equivalent) returns **ONLY** user's friends who use your application. This limitation applies to apps that are on v1.0 mode too.

If you're looking to get friends for tagging actions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends

If you're looking to get friends for inviting to a GAME: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends

Cheers!